# Confused whether to use "in" or "of"

Tags: prepositions

Which do I use in this phrase?

> - ...and support the fact that the setting **of** the story is indeed in India.
> - ...and support the fact that the setting **in** the story is indeed in India.

Comment: You might find the [English Language Learners](http://ell.stackexchange.com) SE of interest.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**While you could understandably express the phrase in both ways the first is the more common**: ***... support the fact that the setting of the story is, indeed, in India.***

Check this [Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=setting+in+the+story%2C+setting+of+the+story&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Csetting%20in%20the%20story%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Csetting%20of%20the%20story%3B%2Cc0) query

Comment: By officially selecting the first (and only) answer posted, you have 1) made a "choice" without benefit of comparison; and 2) disincentivized any further community involvement. Whereas, by postponing official selection until others have responded you avail yourself of the community and the opportunity to make a choice based upon comparison

Comment: True, but let's be gentle with new members :) At least they remembered to choose an answer! :-)

Comment: +1 @Araucaria - I should have included an emoticon, I guess. I was not intending to be harsh, after all OP selected my answer.